# Проведение нагрузочного тестирования retail

Tags: нагрузочное-тестирование

У меня есть вопрос по поводу performance testing in retail.
Необходимо обработать 200 онлайн заказов в 50 приложениях (однотипных) двумя работниками одновременно.

Это webapp, используется работниками склада для виртуального поиска, оформления, упаковки онлайн заказов. Необходимо эмулировать работу 50 складов одновременно с двумя сотрудниками в каждом, которые будут оформлять заказы. URI у всех один, за исключением StoreId в конце. Работники используют iPad.

Какой из инструментов наиболее подойдет для этой цели?

Comment: что у вас за приложение?

Comment: Это webapp, используется работниками склада для виртуального поиска, оформления, упаковки онлайн заказов. 
Необходимо эмулировать работу 50 складов одновременно с двумя сотрудниками в каждом, которые будут оформлять заказы.
URI у всех один, за исключением StoreId в конце. Работники используют iPad.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобных задач подходит несколько инструментов:

- [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)

Comment: Отлично. Буду знать куда копать. А то я уж сомневался, что jmeter подойдёт.